# How does selenium upload a screenshot to remote without local saving?

Tags: python, selenium

How does selenium upload a screenshot to remote without local saving? For example, I want to upload the screenshot of selenium directly to the API interface or the drawing bed(In addition, using Python)

Comment: You want to take a screenshot of a webpage and upload it in-memory to somewhere else? [as `io.BytesIO()`]?

Comment: @Jonathan1609 Yes, such as servers The main problem is that the screenshots are uploaded to other places without being saved locally (for example, the screenshots obtained by selenium be directly used as variables and then transmitted) I didn't find a solution in selenium document (all the pictures in the document are saved locally)